# Is there any way to use Web App Builder NLS(in builder folder) in our widgets?

Tags: arcgis, esri, nls

I have created a widget in web app builder. I want to reuse some common nls tags for my widget, which is already available in WAB's NLS file.

Is there any way to do this without including that file in my widget.

**Updated-**
I have created an NLS for my widget, but I want that text for similar string should be synced with WAB.
Ex. There is 'OK' and 'Cancel' button in my widget. These string is configured in WAB's NLS file.

I want that my widget should fetch these configured text from that NLS file.

***Any hint will be appreciated***.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developers.arcgis.com/web-appbuilder/...

Comment: this is quite useful when we Create custom widgets and themes using webapp builder..
I am also looking for the same...
that would be great If anybody can help....

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution.

WAB stores the NLS configuration into a global variable 'jimuNls'. so we can access it using 'window.jimuNls' or directly 'jimuNls'.